# Why × html entity is &times;

Tags: html, html-entities

Why `x` html entity is `&times;`? Why not `&close;` or something else?

`&times;` = ×
`&cross;` = ✗

Is there some reason for that?

Comment: Frameworks like bootstrap - misuse "&times". This is a multiplication symbol, not a "close" symbol. My advice is to use the letter "x" instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"times" is another word for "multiplied by"

2×3 = 6

Answer (score 3):

Because it can be used as an indicator of number of times, like the indicator on Stack Overflow which shows how many times the questions containing some tag were asked.

E.g.:

[java](/questions/tagged/java) × 823325

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) × 814263

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) × 772389

...